# Building Project Programmatically Fails Using Microsoft.Build

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft.build

I installed the three following packages into my console application:

```
Microsoft.Build
Microsoft.Build.Framework
Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core
Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core
```

And I tried to use the following method to build a project:

```
        static void Build(string projectPath)
        {
            var logger = new ConsoleLogger(LoggerVerbosity.Normal);
            logger.ShowSummary = true;
            var manager = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager;

            var projectInstance = new ProjectInstance(projectPath);
            var result = manager.Build(
                new BuildParameters()
                {
                    DetailedSummary = true,
                    Loggers = new List<ILogger>() { logger }
                },
                new BuildRequestData(projectInstance, new string[] { "Build" }));
            var buildResult = result.ResultsByTarget["Build"];
            var buildResultItems = buildResult.Items;
        }
```

However, after I ran the code, I got the error that described in the following image:

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the best solution is to use `MSBuild` command line in `Process` class. A working sample is as follows:

```
            var buildOutput = new List<string>();
            var buildError = new List<string>();
            var buildProcess = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Enterprise\\MSBuild\\15.0\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe",
                    Arguments = projectPath + " /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Debug",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                }
            };

            buildProcess.Start();
            while (!buildProcess.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {
                buildOutput.Add(buildProcess.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
            }
            while (!buildProcess.StandardError.EndOfStream)
            {
                buildError.Add(buildProcess.StandardError.ReadLine());
            }
```

And then you could use the output to determine whether the build was successful or not. The important note is that you have to find the correct path of `MSBuild.exe` file as there are several versions of this file and in my case (VS 2017) the correct path is the one in the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not using tht right MSBuild version. Try to set the variable explicitly in your .proj :

```
<MSBuildExtensionsPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild</MSBuildExtensionsPath>
```

Comment: I don't have any `MSBuildExtensionPath` configuration in my application's `App.config`

Comment: check "YourAppName.csporj" not "app.config"

Comment: Could you please mention more details with a piece of working code? Something like what does this tag do and where should I put it?

Answer (score 0):

One of BuildRequestData constructor overloads supports a parameter called "toolVersion". Since you are using Visual Studio 2017, set it as "15.0".

**EDIT:** I quitted using the .Net Framework provided MSBuild version (the one located here):
`System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory()`

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

Instead, I'm using the one located here:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\{version}\Bin

This version provide extra parameters as `LangVersion` or `DeployOnBuild`.

Comment: That constructor overload needs other parameters `globalProperties` and `hostServices` what should I set them as?

Comment: Thanks, I tested your solution but it didn't solve my problem. I've changed the screenshot by the way. Could you please take a look at it?

Comment: It looks like you have post-build events. Is it possible? I haven't found yet how to deal with them... If I found the answer in next weeks, I'll update this answer.

Comment: I don't think so, I tried many different things but none worked out for me